# CSS Shine effect on colorized text not working

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to create shine effect on my text like here: https://codepen.io/avstorm/pen/WNrMqjG

My problem is that my text is colorized and the shine in the codepen above is working only when the text is in one color.

I tried my best but got here so far:
https://codepen.io/naoranhaisy/pen/RwZQeeN

HTML:

```
    <span class="shine logoText">
      <span>Peer</span>
      <span>Anfon</span>
      <span>infrustructre</span>
    </span>
```

CSS:

```
.logoText span:first-child {
  color: #4361ad;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.logoText span:nth-child(2) {
  color: #dfdfdf;
  font-size: 29px;
}

.logoText span:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.shine {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #222, #fff);
  background-size: 15px 100%;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: initial;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  animation: shimmer 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: shimmer 2s infinite ease-in out;
}

@keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: top right;
  }
}
```

(As you can see it's not really good...)

Can any css master can help me? Thank you!

Comment: Please explain, what exactly your desired shine `background` effect should be, given your different `text`colors.

Comment: @bitski The letters that are on shine should be in gray color